# Use one uploader of image (carrierwave) for several models in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Here I have two models: User and Book
User has a Avatar to upload, and Book has a Cover to upload
I have read the railscast about uploading images, but I dont know how should I approach different type of images? (In this case, the avatar for User and cover for Book)

I have checked out some open source code for forums. It uses a AvatarUploader and a PhotoUploader, which is to upload photos in a post.

So, Should I use one uploader both for photos and avatars(And How? ) or I just create 2 uploaders for each?
 Thank you !

Comment: How to deal with what? Can you explain where is your problem exactly? There isn't any problem to do two different uploaders or use one for different models.

Comment: Uh.....I'm not sure to use 2 uploader seperately or just 1 uploader for both.

Comment: Be careful with some inheritance pitfalls like [this one](https://gist.github.com/rlivsey/3304402)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's absolutely fine to use two separate uploaders, even if they're nearly identical. They all extend `CarrierWave::Uploader::Base` anyway, it just keeps your objects nice and neatly named.

If you have some shared functionality you want to use in both and don't want to repeat, you could always write your own class that extends `CarrierWave::Uploader::Base` and inherit from those in your uploaders instead!

```
class MyImageUploaderBase < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end

class AvatarUploader < MyImageUploaderBase 
  ...
end
```

Comment: Use of the `version` method in an uploader does not appear to follow in inheritance.  For instance, adding `version :thumb  {process :resize_and_pad => [45, 45] }` [note comment formatting in SO restricts my writing here] is not respected when in your `AvatarUploader`.  @rlivsey 's gist at https://gist.github.com/rlivsey/3304402 shows this too. I think it's not respected in `MyImageUploaderBase` either. In looking at the carrierwave code, it's not apparent to me why it wouldn't be.